# Integrating over a tetrahedron

Tags: integration

Let $S$ be the tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$ having vertices $(0,0,0), (0,1,2), (1,2,3), (-1,1,1)$. Calculate $\int_S f$ where $f(x,y,z) = x + 2y - z$.

Before I show you guys what I have tried, please no solutions. Just small hints. Now, I have been trying to set up the integral by looking at $x$ being bounded between certain planes, etc. I ended up with $$\int_0^{x+2} \int_{\frac{z}{2} - \frac{x}{2}}^2 \int_{2y - z}^{3z - 4y} f\:\: \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z.$$ But this doesn't seem correct. The question came with a hint: To find a linear diffeomorphism $g$ to use as a change of variables, but I have been unable to find such a mapping between $S$ and the unit cube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Let $T$ be the tetrahedron with vertices at the origin and the coordinate unit vectors, i.e., at $(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$.  Compute $\int_T f$.

(2) Find a linear map $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ that maps $T$ to the original tetrahedron $S$.  Since $\varphi$ is linear, it automatically fixes the origin, so it suffices to make sure the other $3$ vertices map correctly.

(3) Use $\varphi$ as a linear change of variables and apply the [change of variable theorem for multiple integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables).

Comment: So let $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by $\varphi(x, y, z) = (z - y, x + y + 2z, 2x + y + 3z)$. The integral of $f$ over $T$ can be set up as $\int_0^{1 - x - y} \int_0^{1-x} \int_0^1 f dxdydz$. Then use the change of variables theorem. Thanks!

Quick question, when I set up the integral of $f$ over $T$, I look at bounds for $x$, $y$, and $z$. When I tried to do the same thing with my tetrahedron $S$, I got nonsense. Was I just doing it wrong (but there's a correct way)? Or is there something that makes that technique infeasible?

Comment: The usual way of determining the limits of integration for a triple integral is to consider the projection of the region onto one of the coordinate planes.  Since none of the faces of $S$ parallels a coordinate plane, this strategy doesn't work very well.  But $S$ *is* bounded by planes, just not the coordinate planes, so we make a change of variable that sends these to the coordinate planes.

Comment: Viktor Vaughn, Thank you very much for your very beautiful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint to your hint: You can find a linear transformation sending the vectors $(0,0,0)(0,1,2)$ etc to the standard basis (actually, it is easiest to compute the inverse to this first). A linear transformation will change area in a uniform way (think about where arbitrary little cubes are sent), and the bounds after applying this transformation will be easier. (The keyword for all of this is determinants.)

Answer (score 0):

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.
This exercise is Exercise 6 on p.151 in section 17 in this book.
I solved this exercise.
Viktor Vaughn's answer is very beautiful.
But my answer is not beautiful.

Let $A:=(0,0,0),B=(1,2,3),C=(0,1,2),D=(-1,1,1)$.
The equation of the plane passing through $A,B,C$ is $p_1(x,y,z)=-x+2y-z=0$.
The equation of the plane passing through $A,B,D$ is $p_2(x,y,z)=-x-4y+3z=0$.
The equation of the plane passing through $A,C,D$ is $p_3(x,y,z)=x+2y-z=0$.
The equation of the plane passing through $B,C,D$ is $p_4(x,y,z)=-x+z=2.$
$p_1(D)>0$.
$p_2(C)>0$.
$p_3(B)>0$.
$p_4(A)<2$.
So, $S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid p_1(x,y,z)>0\text{ and }p_2(x,y,z)>0\text{ and }p_3(x,y,z)>0\text{ and }p_4(x,y,z)<2\}.$
Let $$H:=\begin{pmatrix}-1&2&-1\\-1&-4&3\\1&2&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then $\det H=4\neq 0$.
Let $G:=H^{-1}$.
Then, $$G=\begin{pmatrix}-1/2&0&1/2\\1/2&1/2&1\\1/2&1&3/2\end{pmatrix}.$$
Let $g:\mathbb{R}^3\ni(u,v,w)\mapsto ((-1/2)u+(1/2)w,(1/2)u+(1/2)v+w,(1/2)u+v+(3/2)w)\in\mathbb{R}^3.$
Then, $R:=g^{-1}(S)=\{(u,v,w)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid 0<u\text{ and }0<v\text{ and }0<w\text{ and }u+v+w<2\}.$
$g$ is a diffeomorphism from $R$ to $S$.
$\det Dg=1/4$.
So, by Change of variables theorem, $\int_S x+2y-z=\int_R w\cdot (1/4)=1/6.$